# Search for a record in json with python

Tags: python, json

I need to search through json to find a specific record that matches with a search string, but I need the record number of the match so I can also return other attributes of the same record.

Basically, I have two json sources with multiple records, and each "record" contains multiple attributes.

I'm trying to loop through one of the json files - get a "UUID" for each record from the first json file, then search for a record in the second json file that has a "RecordID" that matches the UUID in the first json file, and then return some of the attributes for each record out of the two files so I can compare some of the attributes.

I'm having a slow day today, so appreciate any help.

Comment: give example please

Answer (score 0):

You may use this as an example.
Just created two different json data for test purposes.
In order to search from both file and get "uuid" I created  getItemWithIndexFromOther function. this one takes json data and index ( uuid ) as parameters and returns properties to combine.

```
jsonData1 = [{"uuid": 1, "word": "word1 "},
             {"uuid": 2, "word": "word2 "},
             {"uuid": 3, "word": "word3 "}]
jsonData2 = [{"uuid": 1, "word": "word1 ",  "otherprop": "other word 1 "},
             {"uuid": 2, "word": "word2 ", "otherprop": "other word 2"},
             {"uuid": 3, "word": "word3 ",  "otherprop": "other word 3"}]


together = [jsonData1, jsonData2]
sourceName = ["jsonData1", "jsonData2"]


def searchJson(keyword, jsonData, jsonname):
    itemsFound = []
    foundItem = {}
    for item in jsonData:

        if keyword in item["word"]:

            if jsonname == "jsonData1":
                jsonOther = 1

            else:
                jsonOther = 0
            jsonOther = 1
            foundItem = item.copy()
            otherJsonItem = getItemWithIndexFromOther(
                item["uuid"], together[jsonOther])

            if otherJsonItem is not None:
                foundItem.update(otherJsonItem)

            itemsFound.append(foundItem)

    return itemsFound


def getItemWithIndexFromOther(ind, jsonData):

    for item in jsonData:

        if int(item["uuid"]) == int(ind):

            return item
    return None


filteredItems1 = searchJson("word3", jsonData1, "jsonData1")
filteredItems2 = searchJson("word3", jsonData2, "jsonData2")

filteredTogether = filteredItems1 + filteredItems2
print(filteredTogether)
```